# How to handle a list of resources with ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-resttemplate, response-entity

I have an external REST API that returns a list of `client` objects as json. For example:

```
GET externalapi.io/api/clients

[ {
    "id" : "b15asgdc-6efd-4a2d-re08-2q3r3bae",
    "clientName" : "test1",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id" : "ryec-6efd-4a2d-aa08-29a9drjrteae",
    "clientName" : "test2",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

My API calls this external service using Spring's RestTemplate. The goal is to get the response and parse it into `client` Java objects. I've tried the following:

```java
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(null, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityJson = resttemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ClientResource>>(){}.getType();

ArrayList<ClientResource> responseResources = gson.fromJson(responseEntityJson.getBody(), listType);
```

My trouble is with this line:

```java
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntityJson = resttemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

My hope was that I could get the body as a JSON string, and use Google's GSON to parse it into objects, but this does not seem to work. I've seen suggestions to use

```java
ResponseEntity<ClientResource> responseEntityJson = resttemplate.exchange(path, HttpMethod.GET, entity, ClientResource.class);
```

but, I don't think this works for a list of resources. I can set `ResponseEntity<List<ClientResource>>` but `.exchange()` doesn't easily accept a type like that. How can I handle a list of resources with ResponseEntity?

Comment: "does not seem to work" -- what happens?

Comment: First error that led me to this was 
`Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String] and content type [application/json]
`. 
I've an http message converter for JSON, but my question is about how to handle a list of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please, maybe it works for you.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
// set headers if required

HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

String url = "https://externalapi.io/api/clients";

ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ClientResource>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ClientResource>>() {};
ResponseEntity<List<ClientResource>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseType);

List<ClientResource> clientResources = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Madan's code should work. Next to using the Gson library from Google you can also use ObjectMapper from the Jackson library.

See the following:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(null, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = resttemplate.exchange(
"https://externalapi.io/api/clients", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<ClientResource> clients = objectMapper.readValue(
response.getBody(), new TypeReference<List<ClientResource>>() {});
```